# Prepopulated Date Using calender in android

Tags: java, android, datepicker, calendar

I want to show the date as "current date-180" days. How can I show this? I am adding my code below. Now I can choose date from datepicker dialog only, can't prepopulate date in textview.

```
Calendar calendarFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePickerFrom = new DatePickerDialog(activity, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            StringBuilder selectedDate = new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth).append("-").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-").append(year);
            textDateFrom.setText(selectedDate);

        }
    }, calendarTwo.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarTwo.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendarFrom .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    textDateFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePickerFrom .getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
            datePickerFrom .show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Even when [the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) doesn’t come built-in on most Android devices yet, for date arithmetic like this, it’s worth considering getting [ThreeTenABP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) and using `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Merida")).minusDays(180)` (fill in your desired time zone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
    Calendar calendarFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarFrom.add (Calendar.DATE, -180);

    System.out.println(calendarFrom.getTime());
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply..i have a text view named " textDateFrom"..how can i do set text this date.pls tell

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat to format the `Date` as returned from `calendarFrom.getTime()`

Comment: thank u ..i will try